# How can I replace a custom token?

Tags: 7, tokens, path-aliases

I am trying to add a custom token in pathauto.
I have a token [story-page-number].
Then in my hook_pathauto_alias_alter() I am trying to replace it using token_replace().

Something is not quite right though.

```
token_replace("[story-page-number]", (array)node_load($context['data']['node']->nid));
```

Here's my custom token set up.

```
function mymodule_token_list($type = 'all') {
    $tokens['story-page-number'] = t('Page number (of story front)');
    return $tokens;
}

function mymodule_token_values($type, $object = NULL, $options = array()) {
    $values = array();
    $values['story-page-number'] = get_story_page_number($node->nid);;  

return $values;
}
```

What am I missing here, I thought it would be a lot more straight forward.

Comment: Is the question for Drupal 6, or Drupal 7? I am asking because you are showing code for Drupal 6, but the tags you are using suggests the question is for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$node = node_load($context['data']['node']->nid);
token_replace("[node:story-page-number]", array('node' => $node));
```

If `$context['data']['node']` is already a node, then you may skip the `node_load()` call, and simply assign `$node = $context['data']['node'];`

**Edit:** Sorry, I didn't try your example in code.  You need to include the token type in your token names. In `mymodule_tokens()`, check to be sure that `$type` is `'node'`, and then look up `$node` from `$data['node']`. Note that you are using the Drupal 6 `hook_token_values()`; you should use the D7 `hook_tokens()`.  Use the implementation of [node_tokens()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tokens.inc/function/node_tokens/7) as a guide.

#### References

- [hook_tokens()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7)
- [token_replace()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!token.inc/function/token_replace/7)

Comment: I tried you changes but still no dice. I've added more to the issue so you can see how my tokens are setup. It's a custom token.

Comment: Could you at least clarify whether this is Drupal 6 or 7? You have the question tagged as 7 but the API you are using is the Drupal 6 one.

Comment: I answered the question for Drupal 7, as the question was tagged 7.  However, since the OP was using the D6 API, it's hard to know if he intended to ask the question regarding D6, or if he was using the wrong API for D7. Since his code was not working, I presumed the later.